# Indexing Server problem

Tags: indexing-service

I've got an HTML file which I'm having a problem with through Index Server.  Here is the text in question.

(B)   **$10,800** per linear mile for

(C)   **$40,000** per linear mile for any

My problem is with the bolded text.

- If I search for **800**, it finds the document
- If I search for **$10**, it finds the document
- If I search for **$40**, it finds the document
- If I search for **$10,800**, **10,800**, **$40,000** or **40,000** it will not find the document, regardless of if I surround the text with double quotes.

I thought perhaps it was the comma, but I can find other documents in the indexing server repository with the 40,000 and it will find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, but would this do better on ServerFault?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I can try there as well.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER MIND!!!

I finally figured it out (after about two days).  There were a series of non-breaking spaces (& nbsp;) right before the text in question.  I replaced the last one with a physical space and re-indexed it - I guess the indexing service isn't smart enough to ignore those or to treat them as **GASP** - A SPACE!